How to auto approve 1 user to a room resource that is managed by a delegate
I have created a Room mailbox
= room@mailbox.com
Current setup is
= Booking delegate settings > Select Deletegates who can accept or decline booking request
== a@b.com
We have directors that need to be auto approved to the calendar

and anyone else will still go through the delegate

how can this be done?
I have not been able to find anything :(

Below will add the group "EMAILADDRESSBYPASS" = which is the email to bypass the delegation and approval process from the "ROOM EMAIL ACCOUNT" mailbox calendar
Set-CalendarProcessing -Identity "ROOM EMAIL ACCOUNT" -AllBookInPolicy $false -BookInPolicy "EMAILADDRESSBYPASS"

Agree with you.
